# Got a Version list as Folders, want to find highest Version

Tags: java, sorting, version, directory

So, i have this List of Folders which represent the Versions of a Program and i want to get the latest (there are some junk files next to the Folders!):

```
0.0.0.256
0.0.1.1
0.0.1.2
0.0.1.5
0.0.1.11
0.0.1.68
0.0.2.1
```

and so on.

If i want to get only the latest Version Folder here, how could i accomplish that?

Currently, i know that the version wont rise higher than 0.0.1.x for now, (the above is only an example) so i could use

```
    for(String name:names)
    {

        if (name.indexOf("0.0.1")==0)
        {


            ret = name;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Current Installed Version Folder: "+ret);
```

but that wont last forever. How could i write some code, that will always give me the highest representive Version number? I can think of a way how to do it right now (checking the 0th char, then the 2nd, 4th and so on) but i think there is a smarter way. Any quick ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea would be to use a comparator to compare each String (I removed the part which was using the Set) :

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    String [] names = { "0.0.1.1",
                        "1.0.1.1",
                        "0.0.1.2",
                        "0.0.1.5",
                        "0.0.1.11",
                        "0.0.0.100",
                        "0.0.0.256",
                        "0.0.2.1",
                        "0.0.1.68"};
    String maxVersion = names[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < names.length; i++){
        if(compare(maxVersion, names[i]) == 1)
            maxVersion = names[i];
    }
    System.out.print(maxVersion);
}
static int compare(String a, String b){
     String[] sA = a.split("\\.");
     String[] sB = b.split("\\.");
     for(int i = 0; i < sA.length; i++){
        int cmp = Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(sB[i]), Integer.parseInt(sA[i]));
        if(cmp != 0)
            return cmp;
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
"1.0.1.1"
```

Note that this assume that each version number has the same length, but you can change this by checking both the length of the resulting arrays when splitting.

---

> i got another problem: i got some files next to the Version Folders,
>   so i can't get the names List from File.list()

You can provide a `FileNameFilter` with the `listFiles` method:

```
File file = new File("/pathToVersionFolders");
File[] files = file.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
  @Override
  public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
      return new File(dir, name).isDirectory();
  }
});
```

Now you have only the directories. If you want to get only the names, you can use [`list`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29).

Comment: Phew, this seems to be more complicated than i thought. I did never work with anything using < and >, i somewhat avoided it. If you can now tell me how i can use this/how it works it would be awesome! Okay, just saw the edit. If I'm right, i should now be able to use `set.pollFirst()` to get the highest Version, right?

Comment: @Marenthyu You'll need to cal `set.first()` because `pollFirst()` removes the element from the collection. But yes the idea is here. Do you want to store all the names in a collection?

Comment: Hm, I am not used to Collections. And actually, i only want to get the newest Version thats all. i am trying to run this in my method "public static String getNewestVersion()"

Comment: @Marenthyu I edited my answer without using collections. The idea remains the same. Note that this assume that each version number has the same length, but you can change this by checking both the lengths of the resulting arrays when splitting.

Comment: okay now. i believe this would work but now i got another problem: i got some files next to the Version Folders, so i can't get the names List from File.list() - any idea for this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46162/discussion-between-marenthyu-and-zouzou)

Comment: @ZouZou just a note. The code only works for versions that have the same length, so it will only work for the special case the OP is describing and will fail as soon as a non conforming directory exists.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings I said it _"Note that this assume that each version number has the same length, but you can change this by checking both the lengths of the resulting arrays when splitting."_

Comment: @ZouZou ok it was burried deep in the comments, maybe you could add it to the answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the Java 8 Stream API you have to write a custom comparator.

```
List<String> sortedVersions = versions.stream().sorted((o1, o2) -> {
     String[] o1Split = o1.split("\\.");
     String[] o2Split = o2.split("\\.");
     int i = 0;
     while (i++ < Math.min(o2Split.length, o1Split.length)) {
         int o1IntValue = Integer.parseInt(o1Split[i - 1]);
         int o2IntValue = Integer.parseInt(o2Split[i - 1]);
        if (o1IntValue != o2IntValue) {
            return o1IntValue - o2IntValue;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());

String highestVersion = sortedVersions.get(sortedVersions.size() - 1);
System.out.println(highestVersion);
```

Answer (score 1):

The currently accepted answer assumes you always have the exact same numbering schemes, which is probably true in your case. The "junk files" that you've mentioned are then filtered out using an `isDirectory()` filter, but what if you had some junk directories?

A more generic solution would not care about the exact versioning scheme, but split the input file names into a set of numeric / non-numeric segments, and then order the files by matching segment numbers (numerically if both are numeric, alphanumerically otherwise). [I've blogged about this approach here](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/02/23/how-to-order-file-names-semantically-in-java/). [The idea was inspired by this answer here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/37217/5314). The comparator could look like this:

```
public final class FilenameComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    private static final Pattern NUMBERS = 
        Pattern.compile("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
    @Override public final int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // Optional "NULLS LAST" semantics:
        if (o1 == null || o2 == null)
            return o1 == null ? o2 == null ? 0 : -1 : 1;

        // Splitting both input strings by the above patterns
        String[] split1 = NUMBERS.split(o1);
        String[] split2 = NUMBERS.split(o2);
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(split1.length, split2.length); i++) {
            char c1 = split1[i].charAt(0);
            char c2 = split2[i].charAt(0);
            int cmp = 0;

            // If both segments start with a digit, sort them numerically using 
            // BigInteger to stay safe
            if (c1 >= '0' && c1 <= '9' && c2 >= 0 && c2 <= '9')
                cmp = new BigInteger(split1[i]).compareTo(new BigInteger(split2[i]));

            // If we haven't sorted numerically before, or if numeric sorting yielded 
            // equality (e.g 007 and 7) then sort lexicographically
            if (cmp == 0)
                cmp = split1[i].compareTo(split2[i]);

            // Abort once some prefix has unequal ordering
            if (cmp != 0)
                return cmp;
        }

        // If we reach this, then both strings have equally ordered prefixes, but 
        // maybe one string is longer than the other (i.e. has more segments)
        return split1.length - split2.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer, it has been a while (4 years almost now) since i asked the question. Looking back at this, i should have thought about it more and would have been able to solve it myself.

Answer (score 0):

The are a lot of solutions. For example

1. split your string by `.`
2. Iterate over the resulting array and create integer by adding current number to the result * 10,
3. Compare resulting numbers

Here is a kind of pseudo code.

```
long version = 0;
String[] parts = versionSpec.split("\\.");
for (String part : parts) {
    int n = part.length;
    version = version * n + Integer.parseInt(part);
}
```

// at this point you have numeric representation of the version.

Now you can compare versions as you want. For example you can implement your own `Comparator`.

EDIT: the solution is fixed. Now `n` is calculated dynamically.

Comment: If i get this right, it should be able to do this if i use my "name" for what you have as "versionSpec", right? I will try to do this right away, just a sec and thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't this break if you have a version numbers like `1.200` and `2.100`?

Comment: @OdayMansour Yes I'm not sure this solution works. I.e 0.0.1.0 is smaller than 0.0.0.68 with this.

Comment: @ZouZou thats right... recognised it when i tested this. sorry AlexR , but this does not seem to work. (i got one folder with version 0.0.0.256)

Comment: @AlexR - any other ideas?

Comment: @Marenthyu, this is not working code. This is a pseudo code I wrote during 30 seconds. Debug it and find why it does not work.

Comment: @AlexR - I know, but i stopped trying to use it, reason above.

Comment: @Marenthyu, take a look on fixed solution. It hopefully should work better.

Answer (score 0):

Since version numbers will always have this structure `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*` then you can scan the directory for folder names that fit this pattern.

Once you've got the list of version directories, then you can split them into the separate numbers (split on the '.' character) and then sort them on the columns going from left to right.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, but if i get right what you're saying then it's not right. Versions would be in the format `[0-infinity]+(\.[0-infinity]+)*`

Comment: This is regex, the pattern `[0-9]+` means any digit from 0-9 repeated one or more times. So here I'm looking for any number value (0 to infinity) followed by zero or more times (hence the `*` character) the pattern `\.[0-9]+` which is `.number` with number from 0 to infinity.

Comment: I am sorry, but i still don't get the idea of this :/

Comment: Look up "Regular Expressions".
`[0-9]` matches any digit from 0 to 9.
`[0-9]+` matches one or more digits from 0 to 9.
`\.` matches the `.` character.
`+` makes regex match the previous pattern one or more times.
`*` makes regex match the previous pattern zero or more times.

`\.[0-9]+` matches `.3`, `.0321`, `.2239487192783948729`.
put that between brackets and add `*` to make regex match it zero or more times.

Put it all together to match any number from 0 to infinity, possibly followed by a dot and then any number from 0 to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but may not work for others depending on how the versions of a program are updated.

I used the `lastModified` property of Files to determine which version directory was the most recent to be modified. In my case, the most recently modified folder was also the most recent / highest version for the program. It saved me a lot of string parsing.

Use `directory.listFiles()` to get an array of all folders in that directory, then pass it to this method to get the index in the array of the last modified folder. fileList[index] would then be the program's latest version folder.

```
/**
 *  Determine the index in an array of files[] of the most recently modified file
 * by comparing the lastModified property from all files in the array.
 *
 * @param  fileList Array of files from a desired directory
 * @return Integer index of most recently modified file/directory.
 * Returns -1 if the File[] array is null. 
 */
public static int getLatestModified(File[] fileList){
    if(fileList!= null){
        long latestVersion = 0;
        int index = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
            File currentDir = fileList[i];
            if(currentDir.lastModified() > latestVersion){
                latestVersion = currentDir.lastModified();
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error: fileList is null.");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Edit: If you have files and folders in the same directory for the versions, you could add an if statement with `isDirectory` to only get the lastModified property from folders.

Answer (score -2):

With Java 8 you can use a stream and the natural order comparator.
for example:

```
List<String> versions = Arrays.asList(
            "0.0.1.1",
            "1.0.1.1",
            "0.2.1.11",
            "0.0.1.2",
            "0.0.1.5",
            "0.1.11",
            "0.1.1.11",
            "0.0.0.100",
            "0.0.0.256",
            "2.0.0.256",
            "1.0.0.256",
            "0.0.2.1",
            "0.0.1.68");

    String highest = versions.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder())
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .get(versions.size() - 1);

    System.out.println(highest);
```

Comment: this won't work, as version 10.0.0.0 would be ranked lower than 2.0.0.0